# How to retrieve the full name of a file when passing it a parameter to a C# program

Tags: c#, windows, string, exe, right-click

I am writing a utility that edits .docx files. I've made it so that when the user right clicks on the correct type of file, it automatically makes the changes and saves the document with a bit of text appended to the file name. All of this works great, except for the fact that I am receiving heavily truncated file names. If the file name contains more than one word, the string passed to the program is has most of its characters replaced by a single ~. Is there any way to either read the original file name, or have the parameter be the full string?

Comment: how are you going about 'receiving' the file names?

Comment: After the user selects to edit using the context menu, I am reading the file name in as one of the args in main(string[] args)

Comment: Can you show example what you are passing to your program and what do you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to what I was trying to do. I ended up using the C# method `Path.GetFullPath`.

```
string path = Path.GetFullPath(originalpath);
```

This outputs the full file name as opposed to the truncated one.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx

Answer (score 1):

File.getCanonicalPath will give you what you want

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa988183(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa988183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, for the reply. That would do what I want except that it's a java method.

Answer (score 0):

Put the whole path between two double quot; like:

```
var fn = "\"C:\\Path With Spaces And Special Characters\\#\\to\\My File.docx\"";
// send fn as an argument to the other process
```